# Scraping specific data inside a table

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, getelementsbytagname

This may be a pretty easy solution but I'm at a loss even though I feel close.

I'm trying to scrape market data from the TMX website, specifically I would like the dividend amount to drop into my excel workbook.

This is the below few lines of code from the "inspect" section.

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <strong>Amount:</strong>&nbsp;
        $0.0495
      </td>
```

I need to get $0.0495 into the workbook and my vba code is the following:

```
For Each htmlELE In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("L10").Value = htmlELE.Children(0).innerText
    End With
```

So, I'm moving through the code but the end keeps picking up "Amount:" and dropping it in the cell instead of the value, what I need, sitting on the next line.

Comment: Copy the inter html then clean it up the value `<td><strong>Amount: strong>&nbsp;$0.0495</td`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim v
For Each htmlELE In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("table")(0). _
               .getElementsByTagName("tr")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")

    v = htmlELE.innerText

    '&nbsp; is CHR(160)
    ActiveSheet.Range("L10").Value = trim(Replace(v, "Amount:" & chr(160),""))

    'or lookfor the $ and take the rest
    p = Instr(v, "$")
    If p > 0 Then ActiveSheet.Range("L10").Value= Mid(v, p)
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, the second half works perfect - "looking for the $ and taking the rest."